# Two CSTR in series (glucose to acetate)

Tags: mathematical-modeling, linear-control

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3xci.jpg)

Hello, I am studying modeling and control course and I'm struggling with drawing neat figure describing the reactor system and to write the differential equations in detail describing the evolution of the variables of the system.

[My scratch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUVTZ.jpg)

This is the way I approached. Is there any mistakes or wrong approach/assumptions that I made? Fill free to give me any advice.

Comment: Put all relevant info in the post itself. (Rather than linking to another source.)